# How do I capture Android http traffic using charles or wireshark (which is on PC) under VPN connection?

Tags: android, networking, tcp, vpn, charles-proxy

I have googled a lot about setting up fiddlers for capturing android traffic. I have tried each of the suggested options. None of them work when there is an active VPN connection.

Setup: Charles or Wireshark is available on PC. Both PC and android device are on same network and on seperate VPN connections.

Tried approaches:

1. **Configuring Wireshark/Charles** – Created a new adhoc wireless network and making the android use the same. Another way was making the laptop as a virtual router or hotspot. None of these methods work when it comes to VPN.
2. **Using TCP/IP monitor available in eclipse** – This is a great tool built in eclipse, but needs hostname and port. For the internal website I do not know the port. Since it is standard http setup, I am assuming it should be either 80 or 8080.
3. **Using different fiddlers available on Play store** – All good fiddlers like tcpdump need the phone to be rooted and that’s not an option for me.
4. **Tethering of PC network onto mobile** - This again fails when it comes to VPN (damn you, VPN)

Anyone with any insight, most welcome !

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [this](https://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/faqs/vpn-not-working-with-charles/) approach? Have you configured proxy on you device connection?

Comment: Yes, I have setup the proxy on my android device. The link you mentioned works fine for VPN on PC.